# Error 13, Permission denied while accessing directory in WSL

Tags: permissions, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Today at last I could finally build my OS. It was downloading for the last 2 days, so I did the build command. It went perfectly well, but then while making the flashable Google Fuchsia IMG as shown in the below screenshot, I got this error.

[image]

The error goes like this:

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/root/fuchsia/prebuilt/third_party/tools/cgpt/linux-x64/cgpt
```

I am totally confused as I never got this error before. I have tried all the chmod commands: chmod 777, chmod 775, chmod 755, chmod +x, chmod go+rx, chmod o+rx. I can't understand what's going on.

Comment: I'm trying to make an IMG to flash on my phone. The source code includes CGPT to make a GPT partition in the IMG. I checked the folder and it does have files in it, but Everytime I try to create an IMG, it gives me the error mentioned above. BTW, this is not WSL, someone changed the question, I'm just using PuTTY to remote into my work machine, which is a physical machine.

Comment: Because I am building with Ubuntu, and the compiler can't access the directory.

Comment: Have you called yourself root or have you installed something as root by copying the directory?

Comment: I was logged in as root, and the files were automatically downloaded in the directory while it was syncing.